# sup and inf of this set

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to find the $\sup M$ and $\inf M$ of the following set:

$$M=\left\{1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n} + 2\left(\frac{n}{2}-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right);~ n \in \mathbb{N^*}\right\}$$

(For $x \in \mathbb{R}$  is  $\lfloor x\rfloor=\max\{n \in \mathbb{Z};~ n\leq x\} $)

Unfortunately i have no idea how to start...

Comment: Consider even and odd $n$ separately, trying to simplify the expression in each case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Consider separately even $n$ and odd $n$. If $n$ is even,

$$1+\frac{(-1)^n}n+2\left(\frac{n}2-\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor\right)=1+\frac1n\;,$$

and if $n$ is odd,

$$1+\frac{(-1)^n}n+2\left(\frac{n}2-\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor\right)=1-\frac1n+2\left(\frac12\right)=2-\frac1n\;.$$

Now list the values of $$1+\frac{(-1)^n}n+2\left(\frac{n}2-\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor\right)$$ for the first few values of $n$, and you should get a pretty good idea of what the set $M$ looks like.

Comment: If n is even, the sup is 1.5 and it has no inf, if n is odd, the inf is 1 and it has no sup

Comment: @fear.xD: For even $n$ it does have an infimum: it just doesn’t have a minimum. What’s the limit of $1+\frac1n$ as $n\to\infty$? Similarly, the values for odd $n$ don’t have a maximum, but they do have a supremum: what’s the limit of $2-\frac1n$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: it goes to  $2$, but i have to find the least upper bound, and i can always find a number, that is between the half of the last calculated value for $2-\frac1n$ and 2

Comment: @fear.xD: I think that you need to review the definition of *least upper bound*: it is **not** the same as *maximum value*. For instance, $1$ is the least upper bound of the set of real numbers in the interval $(0,1)$, even though $1$ is not one of those numbers.

Comment: Ok, so i have to proof: (i) 2 is upper bound of M and (ii) 2 is least upper bound of M. To (i): $2 \geq 2-\frac1n  \Leftrightarrow 0 \ge -\frac1n  \Leftrightarrow 0 \ge-1$. So $2$ is upper bound of M. Is this correct so far?

Comment: @fear.xD: Not quite: you want $2\ge 2-\frac1n$ for **all** $n\ge 1$, so $0\ge-\frac1n$ is not equivalent to $0\ge-1$. However, $0\ge-\frac1n$ is true for all $n\ge 1$, since $\frac1n>0$ for all $n\ge 1$. And we already know that $2>1+\frac1{2n}$ for all $n\ge 1$, so $2$ is an upper bound for $M$. You already noted that if $x<2$, we can find an odd $n$ such that $2-\frac1n>x$, so $2$ must be the **least** upper bound of $M$.

Comment: @fear.xD: That’s when $n$ is odd. Say $n=2k+1$; then $\frac{n}2=k+\frac12$, so $\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor=k$, and subtracting that from $\frac{n}2$ leaves $\frac12$.